# Debugging Python Segmentation Fault occurring in .so file

Tags: python, debugging, segmentation-fault, ctypes, traceback

I am currently running into a bug when accessing a shared object library using Ctypes, code is below. The strange thing is it occurs on rare occasion. I am able to use the API most of them time but on some occasions it produces a seg fault.

Because it doesn't happen frequently I'd prefer not to use gdb to grab the trackback because I'd need to run it numerous amount of times. Is there a way in python to print the trackback or do a core dump so I can debug this bug? How else could I find out what is wrong?

```
client_login = _clientmod.client_login

client_login.argtypes = [ ctypes.c_void_p,
                          ctypes.c_int,
                          ctypes.c_uint ]

client_login.restype = ctypes.c_int
```

The c_void_p is a handle for the interface.

The c_int and c_uint is the login and password respectively.

Answer (score 0):

`ulimit -c` tells the current maximum core size, `ulimit -c unlimited` sets it to, well, unlimited (you may also want to explore `/etc/security/limits.conf` and your environment, like `~/.bashrc`, for that matter).

Regarding stack trace print, there's a [PyExcPrint](https://gist.github.com/toolness/d56c1aab317377d5d17a#file-py_exc_print-py) extension which lets you do that.